# MKL threads capped using anaconda

Tags: python

Lately, I installed Anaconda on a Windows 8 machine in order to install pytorch.
I have a i7 intel processor with 4 cores, using python 3.6.
Whenever I try to set mkl.set_num_threads to 4 or generally more than 3, the mkl.get_max_threads is capped at 2.

I already tried reinstalling everything, using the MKL_NUM_THREADS env variable, Installing numpy by myself using [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) ,and many other suggestions with no luck.

Needless to say, using low number of cores leads to very slow performance.

Hope you guys can help :)

Comment: You are setting mkl.set_num_threads to 4 and you are using KML_NUM_THREADS as env variable . Shouldn't it be MKL_NUM_THREADS env variable?

Comment: I meant MKL not KML, I fixed the typo on my post.

Answer (score 2):

Set the environment variable MKL_DYNAMIC=FALSE before executing Python scripts. This will increase the cap size to actual max.

For further reference:
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-linux-developer-guide/top/managing-performance-and-memory/improving-performance-with-threading/using-additional-threading-control/mkl-dynamic.html

Comment: Your slolution worked, I can control the number of threads.
However, the main problem remains.
Whenever I use torch, the CPU is capped by ~10% even when the number of threads is more than 1.
Additionally, using numpy the CPU usage is higher and uses all cores.